# I am trying to fetch data from Cloud Firestore but the UI takes time to update

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, viewmodel, coroutine

I am trying to get data from documents on Cloud Firestore but some parts of the UI take time to update. The structure of the collections/documents is this:

Post -->  fjwefojfjefjeoif (document) --> Likes (Collection)->Documents with data)

Post -->  fjwefojfjefjeoif (document) --> Comments (Collection)->Documents with data)

Post -->  fjwefojfjefjeoif (document) --> Fields (PostTitle,PostUser, etc)

Screenshot of firebase: https://imgur.com/r3SceYe

I made a ViewModel to retrieve data and I put the data in a MutableLiveList of Post objects. Every Post object has fields like: PostTitle,PostUser, etc. + 2 Lists: PostLikes,PostComments. So when I retrieve a document I go inside Likes,Comments collections inside every post document. Doing so I can set the list PostLikes and PostComments for every Post Object.

The problem is that when I see the posts in my homepage, I will see 0 likes. The likes will update only if the posts are hidden when I scroll. So if I go down on the homepage and go up the posts will have the correct number of likes. There is a delay on updating these likes.

The code for the ViewModel that retrieves the data:

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.stiven.archiumion.entities.Comment
import com.stiven.archiumion.entities.Like
import com.stiven.archiumion.entities.Post


class PostViewModel: ViewModel(){
    private val firestore = Firebase.firestore
    private val postDocuments = MutableLiveData<List<Post>>()

    /*init {
        loadData()
    }*/

    fun loadData() {
        firestore.collection("Posts")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { posts ->
                val list = mutableListOf<Post>()
                val commentsList = mutableListOf<Comment>()
                
                //For each post I get the likes and comments 
                for (post in posts) {
                    val likesList = mutableListOf<Like>()
                    post.reference.collection("Likes").get().addOnSuccessListener { likes->
                        for (like in likes){
                            val likeObject = like.toObject(Like::class.java)
                            likesList.add(likeObject)
                        }
                    }
                    post.reference.collection("Comments").get().addOnSuccessListener{comments->
                        for(comment in comments){
                            val commentObject = comment.toObject(Comment::class.java)
                            commentsList.add(commentObject)
                        }
                    }
                   
                    //I create the Post object after the likes and comments have been retrieved
                    val postObject = Post(
                        post.getString("PostUser")!!,
                        post.getString("PostTitle")!!,
                        post.getString("PostDescription")!!,
                        post.getString("PostDate")!!,
                        post.getString("PostImage")!!,
                        post.getString("PostTag")!!,
                        likesList,
                        commentsList
                    )
                    list.add(postObject)
                }
                postDocuments.value = list
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }

    }

    @Composable
    fun getDocuments(): LiveData<List<Post>> {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit){
            loadData()
        }
        return postDocuments
    }
}
```

Post object:

```
class Post (
    var PostUser: String = "",

    val PostTitle : String = "",

    val PostDescription : String = "",

    val PostDate : String = "",

    val PostImage : String = "",

    val PostTag : String = "",

    var PostLikes : List<Like>,

    var PostComments : List<Comment>

)
```

I tried using coroutines but I don't think I am using them correctly. It may be that I don't understand the process of retrieving data from firebase but how come likes and comments are not correct as the Post object creates only when a list of likes and comments is created.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated my post as you said. The code works, it retrieves data as it should. As you can see in the Post.kt file there are 2 lists: List<Like> and List<Comment>. These lists contain the documents retrieved from Likes and Comments sub-collection in firebase. There is a delay when retrieving the documents in these sub-collections, so initially the lists will have 0 elements as per default and then it will finish retrieving the likes and comments. The problem is that the UI gets data from ViewModel even-though the ViewModel hasn't finished retrieving the data I want.

Comment: That's the normal behavior since reading data from Firebase takes time. The more documents you read, the longer it will take.

Comment: Yes I understand but I noticed a strange behaviour. The app retrieves data from firestore with a delay of around 1 sec but the likes and comments data will be retrieved and updated only when I scroll. More precisely, the first post initially shows 0 likes, if I scroll to see other posts and the get back to the first post I can see that is updated to the correct number of likes it really has. I was hoping to find a way in order to firstly wait for the data to fetch and then update the UI